# PHP: Regex inquiry

Tags: php, regex

$regex = '/[aeiou]*/'

Would that match "aeiioauo"
or only "aaaaaaaaaaaa," "eeeeeee", "iiiii", etc (zero or more of only one of the characters in the set).

Thank you

Comment: Well, only one way to find out... try it yourself.

Comment: it would match any string. including blank, strings with no vowels, numbers, anything.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no serious answer here, I'd give a serious answer.

When you pass this:

```
$regex = '/[aeiou]*/'
```

to `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` (or a few other functions), it will report a match on **any string**.

`preg_match`, `preg_match_all`, `preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback` all by default will find *non-overlapping* **substring(s)** that matches the regex. (Other languages may have function that asserts **the whole string** matches the regex, which is different).

`[aeiou]*` will match any of the vowels (in English), **0** or more times, appearing consecutively. Since the regex also matches when there is no character at all (**empty string**), and empty string can be anywhere in any string, you will always get at least one match.

To check that a string *contains of only vowels*, you need to *anchor* the regex, with `^` denotes the beginning of the string and `$` denotes the end of the string:

```
$regex = '/^[aeiou]*$/'
```

The regex above will only match when the input string contains only vowels, or is empty string.
Example of matches: `aeuuuooiiii`, (empty string), `a`.
Example of non-matches: `aaaaaaaaaab`, `#@#$`

If you want to match some consecutive sequence (substring) of vowels in an input string, you should make it at least match 1 vowel: so we use `+` in place of `*`

```
$regex = '/[aeiou]+/'
```

Example of matches: `eeee` and `iiuo` in `ffffeeeeddiiuo`; `e` in `red`
Example of non-matches: no match for `nthng 2 s hr`

Hope this helps as a beginner's tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. `[]` means any of set, so it will meet the requirement. But as you do not have additional conditions, this will match any other string too.

Comment: mmmmm....meat....time for lunch

Comment: @JonathanKuhn tnx! ))) my english is very far from good one!)))

Answer (score 0):

The regex will match all characters it can, because regexes are greedy by default. By the way: it will not only match iiiii and the like, but also aeiio and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Using that regular expression would match "aeiioauo" or only "aaaaaaaaaaaa," "eeeeeee", "iiiii"

But it would also match spaces, therefore "aaaaeeee iiiiii" would match as

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
   (
        [0] => aaaaeeee
        [1] => 
        [2] => iiiiii
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
    )

)
```

Instead Of

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => aaaaeeee
        [1] => iiiiii
    )

)
```

So I recommend changing the ' * ' to a ' + '

```
FROM --> $regex = '/[aeiou]*/';

TO   --> $regex = '/[aeiou]+/';
```

EDIT: Here is a useful site for testing regular expressions in php

http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm